# Can we draw a diagram like this?

Tags: diagrams

Can we draw a diagram like this?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX StackExchange! The tool I would suggest first is [`pgfplots`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots). What have you tried so far? If you have code where you are stuck, we'd be happy to help if you edit it into your question. If you haven't done anything so far, the documentation is your friend on where to get started :)

Comment: sorry, i have a deadline tomorrow, I was hoping to get the latex code from someone else...

Comment: Ahh, I see. While I didn't downvote your question, on this site, we want posters to show an attempt rather than simply doing it all ourselves. Professional graphic designers get paid quite handsomely to make illustrations for books/journals, yet most of us write our answers for free! So, demonstrated effort matters greatly to us here. (Beyond just the etiquette on our site, please don't ask to copy code for your assignments...)

Comment: @Rowing0914, with the deadline in mind, I suggest using \includegraphics from package graphicx and just show the bitmap.

Comment: So the 'we' is what? The royal 'we'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

Code (change color and dimensions as You like):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}


\begin{document}
    
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\small]
            %
            %\draw[gray!20,step=0.5cm] (-6.5,-1) grid (6.5,6.5);
            %
            \draw[->,thick] (-6.6,0) -- (6.6,0) node[anchor=west]{$x$};
            \draw[->,thick] (0,-1) -- (0,6.6) node[anchor=south]{$y$};
            %
            \foreach \x in {-6,-5,...,6} \draw [thick](\x cm,-2pt) -- (\x cm,2pt);
            \foreach \y in {-1,0,...,6} \draw [thick](-2pt,\y) -- (2pt,\y);
            %
            \foreach \x in {-6,-5,...,6} \draw (\x cm, 0 cm) node[anchor=north]{\x};
            \foreach \y in {-1,0,...,6}  \draw (0 cm, \y cm) node[anchor=east]{\y};
            %
            \clip (-6.2,0) rectangle (6.2,6.5);
            \filldraw[orange!20,draw=red,line width=2pt,opacity=.5] (0,0) ellipse (6 and 4.5);
            \filldraw[cyan!20,draw=cyan,line width=2pt,opacity=.5] (0,0) ellipse (4.5 and 3);
            \filldraw[green!20,draw=green,line width=2pt,opacity=.5] (0,0) ellipse (3.5 and 2);
            \filldraw[red!20,draw=red,line width=2pt,opacity=.5] (0,0) ellipse (2.5 and 1.2);
            \filldraw[yellow!20,draw=yellow,line width=2pt,opacity=.5] (0,0) ellipse (1.5 and .6);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!